# NaN in Knockout Template

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

I am using Knockout as a View Model to fill values of my view template, It is working fine for all except one function  **getConvertedTotal** is returning NaN.

```
define([
'ko',
'uiComponent',
'mage/url',
'mage/storage',
'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
],function (ko, Component, urlBuilder,storage,quote) 
{
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {template: 'Ishaq_CheckoutTotal/custom-block-order-summary',},
        initialize: function(config) {
            this._super();
            var currencyRate = config.currencyRate;
            var currencySymbol = config.currencySymbol;
        },
        getSubtotal: function() {
            var totals = quote.totals();
            return (totals ? totals : quote)['subtotal'];
        },
        getGrandTotal: function() {
            var totals = quote.totals();
            return (totals ? totals : quote)['grand_total'] ;            
        },
        getConvertedTotal: function() {
            var totals = quote.totals();
            var temp = (totals ? totals : quote)['grand_total'] ;
            return (temp*this.currencyRate);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means one of your values are not a number, either `temp` or `this.currencyRate`. My guess is that `this.currencyRate` is not returning a number (probably `undefined`).

In that case you need to change:

```
var currencyRate = config.currencyRate
```

to

```
this.currencyRate = config.currencyRate
```

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious from the code that `this.currencyRate` is undefined

Comment: Inside getConvertedTotal function unable to get value it is undefined, however inside `initialize: function(config) ` I am able to get data using console.log

Comment: I really hope you spend your time to learn some basic about javascript, this will save you alot of time when learning Magento or any other framework/library

Comment: @ishaq That is because your `currencySymbol` variable is only available within the `initialize` function. You need to change it to `this.currencyRate = config.currencyRate`